# Recurring email in Google Apps for Business

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, automation

I need to send out weekly reminder emails from my Google Apps for Business account but it is going to be tedious and error-prone to have to manually remember and send the emails out. Can I automate recurring emails? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to do this via the Gmail web app itself.

"Delayed/scheduled send" is a [popular feature request](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/PEMdJEPgohs) for Gmail, so this may change in the future.

[Boomerang](http://www.boomeranggmail.com/l/how-to-send-recurring-emails.html) is a popular 3rd party tool that can send scheduled or recurring emails.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to rely on third-party tools, you could create an script by using the Mail or Gmail Services and time-driven trigger but you should have basic programming skills and knowing a bit on JavaScript, HTML and CSS.